# ETSI Definition of "Channelized system"

Tags: rf, terminology, standard

ETSI standards [EN 301 489-1](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/301400_301499/30148901/02.02.03_60/en_30148901v020203p.pdf) and [EN 300 330](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/300300_300399/300330/02.01.01_60/en_300330v020101p.pdf) use the term "channelized" (system or equipment).
But I could not find any definition for "channelized" in one of the standards or any other sources.

What is the official definition for "channelized" in this context?

I would assume wireless lan or mobile/cell phone communication to be "channelized" because of the distinct communication channels and defined frequency bands, but e.g. NFC/RFID to be non-channelized. Is this correct? Is there any official source for this interpretation?

Comment: Please provide links to those standards or copy and paste the pertinent section as an image. Add it to your question.

Comment: I added the links (see above).

Comment: I think google might be your main hope.

Comment: The ETSI standards leave a lot to be desired/to the imagination when it comes to formal definitions of terms... The official source is supposedly EN 300 330-1 3.1 but it doesn't define any of these terms.

I guess the standard is written broad enough to cover cases where you just toss out a "broadband" signal in the middle of a license free band, with whatever modulation you like.

Comment: The most common use-case for short range devices is probably FSK modulation with equipment that works in a somewhat strictly regulated band with channel separation requirements. A channel is the location in the assigned band where your equipment is currently working. Then all the restrictions regarding adjacent channel selectivity etc apply.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a definition

**Channelization**

The process of filtering out the unwanted components of signal from its original form and reducing the
sample rate to the minimum required by the signal of interest is called channelization.

Comment: can someone explain the (-1)